# A question on The Prime Factorization of a Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I just proved the following theorem:

> Let $F$ be a field. A non-scalar monic polynomial in $F[x]$ can be factored as a product of monic prime polynomials in $F[x]$ in one and only one way except for order.

In some problems, I see that this theorem is used for polynomials which are not monic and still the factorization is assumed to be unique up to the order.  My question is that will this statement still be true if I remove the word "monic" from in front of "polynomial" and "prime polynomial"?

Comment: The theorem is still valid , if you add the deatil : "upto association". That means that we can multiply a polynomial with a unit and it is considered to be the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

A ring $F[x]$ is a Unique Factorization Domain (UFD) (proof below) so you can write any non-zero *non-unit* element as a product of primes up to order and up to *units*.

Now, look what are the units in $F[x]$. If $a\neq 0$ and there is $b$ such that $ba=1$ then necessarily those are both degree zero polynomials (or in your terminology *scalars*). Note that this is not true for polynomials over rings with zero divisors. But for polynomials over domains, this is clear.
Observe that opposite inclusion is also true. Take a scalar, ie. element of $F$ then it is invertible as $F$ is a field.

So if we lose the condition of polynomials being *monic* we still have a unique decomposition but **up to units** (or up to *association* in different terminology).

*Now to show that $F[x]$ is UFD*. One can either use Theorem that polynomials over UFD are UFD. Or one can go directly. I am not sure what definition of UFDs you used in your course  of algebra but this one should be rather well-known:

1 **GCD always exists** (unique up to association) - you can easily check that division with remainder works for polynomials (with the remainder having lesser degree then divisor)

2 **Ascending Chain Condition on Principle Ideals** - this one can be more abstract but one can rephrased it as follows: there exists no infinite chain of divisors $... |r_n|r_{n-1}| ... |r_2|r_1$ where each $r_i/r_{i+1}$ is non-unit. Now clearly if one polynomial divides the other and the result of the division is non-unit (not a scalar) then they have a different degree.